# Positioning divs[CSS/HTML]

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to copy the Google HomePage(it's my first project) and I have some questions:

1. My nav bar place is good(top right), but how can I place the Google logo + search bar at that exact position? I tried placing at center both vertically and horizontally but don't work.
2. How can I make the width of the search bar to be equal with logo's width?
3. Why if I'm not using float, my "Google Search" and "I'm feeling Lucky" buttons aren't on same line?

   [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bnows)

Comment: Have you tried using your browsers development tools to see how google do it?

Comment: Yes, but without success(i had some success with buttons style using developer tools, though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center your page you need to give a width and `margin:0 auto;` to your wrapper div `.body`.
Once that is done you can give your search box a s width of 100%. See if that helps.

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrdBn)

Answer (score 0):

3: read some stuff about float and blocks (display: block): http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

To get the "Google search" and "I'm Feeling Lucky" on the same line, make sure there is enough horizontal room for them both and then use display: inline.